# How can i store encryption key into Microsoft provided Key container?

Tags: cryptography, key-management, windows-dpapi

I'm working on an application in which user will enter encryption key via GUI and my app will fetch that encryption key. Now i need to store that received key into Microsoft key container. I got [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb204778(v=vs.85).aspx) and [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms867086.aspx) as a starting point and i know that i have to use this only. I am able to create key inside the container but i don't want to use this key. I have to store user entered key inside the container for later use in encryption/decryption process. Help highly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think the link you provided above is one off--check [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb427412%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead, which covers key import (what you need to start with). In short, you'll invoke [`BCryptImportKey`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375475%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [`BCryptImportKeyPair`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375472%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), depending on if you're dealing with symmetric or asymmetric keys.

Once imported, use the [various functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376208%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) provided in [CNG](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375276%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), probably starting with [`BCryptDecrypt`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375391(v=vs.85).aspx) and [`BCryptEncrypt`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375421(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I tried to use this [example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376234(v=vs.85).aspx#encrypting_data_example) but it returned me 'BCryptOpenAlgorithmProvider@24' not declared. After lots of googling i come to know that to use this function required lib is crypt32.lib. I linked that lib file even though getting same error. Now i want to know whether it's possible to do what i want to do. I want to save my own key in to key container. is it possible? If yes can you explain some what in detail? I as stucked here since last 10 days. Help me.